# Is there any way to make a photo frame app in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, ios, cordova

I want to make an application in which a'll capture a picture and crop face of person and then embed this face to my frame is there any way in phone gap to solve my problem.

Give me some idea how to start with?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You asked for an idea, here it is :)**

Ok so you need to combine multible different features here.

1) PhoneGap Camera API:  http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera

2) Javascript image crop script: http://deepliquid.com/projects/Jcrop/demos.php?demo=live_crop

3) Javascript face detection: http://facedetection.jaysalvat.com/#

PhoneGap can only offer you to make a direct communication with a smartphones features.  Like the camera which you want to use.

If you dont directly want to take the picture yourself you can ofcourse load am image from the smartphones "picture libary".

---

### **Or go native**

You can always try to find some native plugins for these tasks as i already mentioned.

I hope this was of some help.